# How to install gpg keys from behind a firewall?

Tags: firewall, gpg

I understand that keyservers are using the port 11371 but in many cases you are not allowed to connect to this port and you cannot add

There a many cases when you cannot modify the firewall configuration.

Example command that fails

```
 gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0A5174AF
```

**How do you solve this issue?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some key servers answer to port 80 as well:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://wwwkeys.de.pgp.net:80 --recv-keys 0A5174AF
```

And since hkp relies on http, you should be able to use it trough a web proxy too.

Comment: Ubuntu solve this problem and now the server also responds on port 80.

Comment: `wwwkeys.de.pgp.net:80` does not work anymore.

Comment: hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80  works.

Comment: also `hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80`

Answer (score 20):

Something like

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
    --keyserver-options "timeout=40 http-proxy=$http_proxy" \
    --recv-keys B0F4253373F8F6F510D42178520A9993A1C052F8
```

The decisive part is `http-proxy=$http_proxy`, which can be replaced with `http-proxy=http://corporate.proxy.test:8765` for example.

---

BTW: https://askubuntu.com/a/102505/519948

Comment: Important to note that the order of the flags is important here. If you put `--recv-keys` before `--keyserver-options`, you'll get an error that looks like: `gpg: Note: '--keyserver-options' is not considered an option
gpg: "--keyserver-options" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: "timeout=10 http-proxy=http://fooproxy:8080" not a key ID: skipping
`

Comment: The manual page states that keyserver-options can be comma or space delimited, but I found the comma necessary whilst space-delimiting resulting in a gpg usage error.  gpg version 2.0.22.  Like: `--keyserver-options "timeout=10,http-proxy=${http_proxy}"`

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy="http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_server_addr>:<proxy_port>" --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys <key_to_import>
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please provide context around commands so others will have some idea what it is supposed to do and why it’s a solution. - Using a proxy is often a good solution though.

Answer (score 3):

Answers suggesting using key servers that listen on Port 80 will work. Another alternative that offers greater privacy and security is:

#### Use HKPS (HKP over TLS)

This encrypts the connection to the keyserver and helps prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. Also, TCP Port 443 is just as unlikely to be blocked by a corporate firewall as Port 80 (unlike Port 11371).

```
gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Note: the URIs, `https://keyserver.ubuntu.com`, `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com`, `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443` are all equivalent.

#### Configuring this as the default server

Since the release of GnuPG 2.1.9 (2015-10-09), the `--keyserver` option for `gpg` has been deprecated and users are recommended to “use the `--keyserver` in `dirmngr.conf` instead”. The user’s default keyserver can be configured permanently by editing `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

If the `dirmngr` daemon is already running, you’ll need to run `gpgconf --reload dirmngr` for the new configuration to take effect.

#### System default keyservers

Currently (since versions 2.2.29 and 2.3.2, released in July/August 2021), the GnuPG project has `keyserver.ubuntu.com` configured as its default keyserver if none is specified by the user while Debian (and Ubuntu) packages of `gnupg2` have configured `hkps://keys.openpgp.org` as the default keyserver since `gnupg2 2.2.17-1` (released in 2019).

Note: other answers suggest using [SKS keyserver pools](https://sks-keyservers.net/). Unfortunately, these have suffered privacy and abuse problems and, as of June 2021, are no longer operating.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a few notes here.

The manual page for gpg notes that the `--keyserver-options "http-proxy=foo"` will override the `http_proxy` environment variable, but at least for...

`gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
libgcrypt 1.7.9`

It fails to pick up the `http_proxy` environment variable (or `HTTP_PROXY`) but does accept the `--keyserver-options` solution.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to this site? I suspect that the options switch overwrites the proxy variable, but only for this one command. The http_proxy variable is then unchanged to the old one. However, it is not perfectly programmed if the http_proxy and no_proxy variables are ignored.

Comment: I don't understand why apt, Java and gpg need their own proxy definitions anyway. They should, in my opinion, use the default environment variables! There is a trick for apt. Just create an empty /etc/apt/apt.conf. LOL, who makes this up?