# keyserver.ubuntu.com not reachable from new google cloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

```
curl keyserver.ubuntu.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to keyserver.ubuntu.com port 80: Connection timed out

telnet keyserver.ubuntu.com 80
Trying 162.213.33.8...
Trying 162.213.33.9...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

telnet -4 keyserver.ubuntu.com 80
Trying 162.213.33.8...
Trying 162.213.33.9...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

traceroute to keyserver.ubuntu.com (162.213.33.9), 64 hops max
  1   209.85.143.102  10.756ms  *  10.504ms
  2   72.14.233.11  24.571ms  11.599ms  22.782ms
  3   108.170.243.212  10.598ms  10.212ms  10.318ms
  4   208.115.136.37  10.572ms  11.283ms  10.930ms
  5   184.105.223.177  18.702ms  18.391ms  19.591ms
  6   184.104.192.117  18.703ms  18.585ms  18.952ms
  7   184.105.64.62  39.313ms  39.087ms  39.005ms
  8   209.51.171.154  38.966ms  38.652ms  38.770ms
  9   *  *  *
 10   *  *  *
 11   91.189.93.134  102.964ms  102.581ms  102.642ms
 12   91.189.93.205  101.849ms  101.764ms  101.743ms
 13   *  *  *
 14   *  *  *
 15   *  *  *
 16   *  *  *
 17   *  *  *
 18   *  *  *
```

Every other outgoing request works. I've tried various hosts including `bing.com, amazon.com` and there's no issues, but `keyserver.ubuntu.com` times out. It works from my local though.

VPC network routes allow egress to 0.0.0.0/0 and there are no firewall rules defined for egress.

Ubuntu firewall is inactive.

I've tried forcing IPV4 but makes no difference.

Am completely at wits end why this isn't reachable. Any ideas? What can I do next to diagnose this?

Comment: Currently, there is a internet outage that affects many services between ISP's - GCP is one of them.

Comment: @Orphans can I follow this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is 3 years old, but if anyone else stumbles on this like I did, then just pre-pending the `keyserver.ubuntu.com` with `hkps://` seemed to do the trick for me. Seems some guides/tutorials out there might not include that detail.

Someone answered in detail here:

- [How to install gpg keys from behind a firewall?](https://serverfault.com/questions/168826/how-to-install-gpg-keys-from-behind-a-firewall/1088077#1088077)